# Mirror repository from Azure repos on GitLab

Tags: git, azure-devops, mirroring

I need to mirror a repository in Azure Repos with a repository in GitLab (pull), on Gitlab it asks me to insert the repository URL (which I have) and it asks me for a password, I've tried with my outlook password and some credentials I created on Azure Repos, but none are working. Is there another password?

[image]

I had no problem mirroring from GitHub, but I haven't been able to do the same with Azure Repos, and I'd like to have everything on GitLab.

I'm trying this:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First your have to create your **personal access token** in **Azure DevOps** (see user settings). The **name of the token will be the username** which you have to use in GitLab. A scope of "Code : read" should be enough for the token.

In GitLab you have to use the url as described in the [help](https://by-gitlab.de.bayer.cnb/help/workflow/repository_mirroring#pulling-from-a-remote-repository-starter):

- Include the username in the URL if required: `https://username@gitlab.company.com/group/project.git`.

**The username is the name of your DevOps token. And as the password you have to use the token himself.**

Answer (score 0):

To add on previous solution. I was able to mirror without creating a token

For pull Request:

```
https://<username>@gitlab.com/group.project.git
```

Username: your gitlab username
Password: your gitlab password

Try pulling the repo locally using this command

```
git clone https://<username>:<password>@gitlab.com/group/project.git
```

If git clone works, then mirroring should work as well

Note :
**that having an "@" in your password fails the git command.** this is usual suspect